# Iterating multidimensional array with numpy, python and open cv2.4

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, python-2.7

Lately I have posted a question about this but in the end I solved it in a *non-elegant* manner.

I have 2 images that are numpy arrays and I would like to create a new array iterating the 2 images. I have 3 cases and I have done the following:

```
delta= np.empty((h, w, 3),int)
    for z in range (0,3):
      for i in range(0, (h-1)):
        for j in range(0, (w-1)):
         delta[i][j][z]=np.sqrt(((imgLlab[i][j][0]-imgRlab[i][j-disp[i][j]][0])**2) + ((imgLlab[i][j][1]-imgRlab[i][j-disp[i][j]][1])**2) + ((imgLlab[i][j][2]-imgRlab[i][j-disp[i][j]][2])**2) )


delta= np.empty((h, w, 3),int)
    for z in range (0,3):
     for i in range(0, (h-1)):
    for j in range(0, (w-1)):
       delta[i][j][z]=np.sqrt(((imgLlab[i][j][0]-imgRlab[i][j-disp[i][j]][0])**2)  )


for z in range (0,3):
 for i in range(0, (h-1)):
  for j in range(0, (w-1)):
    delta[i][j][z]=np.sqrt(((imgLlab[i][j][1]-imgRlab[i][j-disp[i][j]][1])**2) + ((imgLlab[i][j][2]-imgRlab[i][j-disp[i][j]][2])**2) )
```

I would like to not repeat iterating every time and do it as quickly as possible.

Is there another way to do this with numpy?

EDIT
after Jaime help, i have changed my code like that:

```
disp= np.hstack([disp, disp, disp]).reshape(h,w,3).astype(np.int)
rows = np.arange(h).reshape(h, 1, 1)
cols = np.arange(w).reshape(1, w, 1)
planes = np.arange(3).reshape(1, 1, 3)
print rows.shape, cols.shape, planes.shape, disp.shape, h
data = imgLlab[rows, cols, planes] - imgRlab[rows ,cols - disp[rows, cols, planes], planes]
data = data**2
data = np.sum(data, axis=-1)
data = np.sqrt(data)
```

i had to reshape dist because it didn't have the same shape of imglLab and imgRLab, i mean imglLab is (288, 384,3) and disp was (288,384).
Also if i print disp(288,384,1) i get the same error, its like there is no value there but the dimension is the same like the others ones.
But now that the 3 arrays got the same dimension i get an indexError: index (384) out of range (0<=index(383) in dimension 1.

Comment: Are you excluding the last row and column of each image on purpose, i.e. why aren't you iterating as `for j in range(h):`? Also, your iteration over `z` is computing the same value every time, is that what you really want?

Comment: they are two images and h is the height and w is the width. I am iterating over z because i want that this array will be an image and if i don't have the 3 channel i can't save it (maybe yes).
I am not excluding the last row and column on purpose because if i remove (h-1) i get an index out of bounds error.
Did i answer to you?

Comment: Your stacking of the three copies of `disp` is what is giving you the problem. Using 'hstack would be consistent with a `reshape(h, 3, w)`, for yours you would want to use `np.dstack`.

Comment: But you don't need to stack three copies of the same array: simply reshape it to `(h, w, 1)` and when you create `data`change the indexing of ìmgRlab` to `imgRlab[rows ,cols - disp[rows, cols, :], planes]`.

Comment: I think 'disp' has some probllem with the last value, because if i create and array like that: 'arr=np.zeros_like(disp)'
and i put arr in my formula it works fine.
Is there a way to put a 0 at the end of 'disp'? maybe it gives me trouble because there is no value there or how can i change the shape of those images like '(h-1,w-1,3)' because i have tried with 'reshape' but it doesn't work

Comment: the problem was here:
rows = np.arange(h-1).reshape(h-1, 1, 1)
cols = np.arange(w-1).reshape(1, w-1, 1)

now it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you can improve in your code.

1. Do not index your arrays as `arr[a][b][c]`. When doing that, you are effectively creating a python object `arr[a]`, which is then used to create a new python object `arr[a][b]` from which your desired object, `arr[a][b][c]` is constructed. All that intermediate constructing and destructing is eliminated if you use numpy's tuple indexing as `arr[a, b, c]`.
2. Don't use loops when they are not needed! Instead of

   ```
   for j in xrange(len(a)) :
       a[j] = b[j]
   ```

   you can do

   ```
   a[:] = b[:]
   ```

   and this is actually the kind of stuff that makes numpy great, so use it!

As for speeding up your code... You should check that `imgLlab.shape`, `imgRlab.shape` and `disp.shape` are all the same, `(h, w, 3)`. Your index error suggest that one of them is smaller. Anyway, to get what you are after we need to take advantage of [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [fancy indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html). Read and digest those links, or the following will make little sense:

```
rows = np.arange(h).reshape(h, 1, 1)
cols = np.arange(w).reshape(1, w, 1)
planes = np.arange(3).reshape(1, 1, 3)
data = imgLlab[rows, cols, planes] - \ 
       imgRlab[planes, rows - disp[rows, cols, planes], planes]
# data is of shape (h, w, 3)
data = data**2
# data is of shape (h, w, 3)
data = np.sum(data, axis=-1)
# data is of shape (h, w)
data = np.sqrt(data)
# data is of shape (h, w)
```

If you really want to copy the exact same array to the three planes of your `delta` array, you can do it as:

```
delta[...] = data.reshape(h, w, 1) # equivalent to data.reshape(-1, 1)
```

This was only your first case, but the others should be easy to build from this first example, once you understand what is going on. If you have trouble, come back and ask!